# What is the difference between the declarative_base() and db.Model?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

The [quickstart tutorial](http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-SQLAlchemy/quickstart.html) for the Flask-SQLAlchemy plugin instructs users to create table models inheriting the `db.Model` class, e.g.

```
app = Flask(__main__)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
class Users(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    ...
```

However, the [SQLAlchemy tutorial](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/tutorial.html) and the bottle-SQLAlchemy [README](https://github.com/iurisilvio/bottle-sqlalchemy) both suggest that table models inherit a `Base` instantiated from `declarative_base()`.

```
Base = declarative_base()
class Users(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    ...
```

What is the difference between these two approaches?

Answer (score 120, accepted):

Looking in the Flask-SQLAlchemy source code the `db.Model` class is initialized as follows:

```
self.Model = self.make_declarative_base()
```

And here is the `make_declarative_base()` method:

```
def make_declarative_base(self):
    """Creates the declarative base."""
    base = declarative_base(cls=Model, name='Model',
                            metaclass=_BoundDeclarativeMeta)
    base.query = _QueryProperty(self)
    return base
```

The `_BoundDeclarativeMeta` metaclass is a subclass of SQLAlchemy's `DeclarativeMeta`, it simply adds support for computing a default value for `__tablename__` (the table name) and also to handle binds.

The `base.query` property enables Flask-SQLAlchemy based models to access a query object as `Model.query` instead of SQLAlchemy's `session.query(Model)`.

The `_QueryProperty` query class is also subclassed from SQLAlchemy's query. The Flask-SQLAlchemy subclass adds three additional query methods that do not exist in SQLAlchemy: `get_or_404()`, `first_or_404()` and `paginate()`.

I believe these are the only differences.

Comment: I was just searching for this today for this app I've been building for a year or so, originally based off your "Mega Flask Tutorial," which uses db.Model rather than explicitly using Base = Declarative_Base. I got confused because my models all clearly use the Declarative extension but yet I had never called declarative_base(). Thanks for the great explanation!

Comment: Is it possible to use db.Model in one User Model and Base in Address Model. For example:- class User(db.Model), class Address(Base)?

Comment: Not sure, but my guess is that some things are not going to work. Flask-SQLAlchemy adds some behavior to the base in the `db.Model` class, so any models that inherit directly from the declarative base are not going to have that.

Comment: Can anyone still explain when to use which one and what are the benefits of declarative base? Also, how to add pagination in declarative base?

Comment: @KarishmaSukhwani if you are using flask-sqlalchemy, use db.Model. if you are using sqlalchemy directly, use declarative_base.

Comment: I was using sqlalchemy within flask with declarative_base but some features like pagination was lagging and it was complicated to make another base class with mixin. so I moved back to flask-sqlalchemy now.
Thanks. @MiguelGrinberg

Comment: for anyone wondering, like me, the `metadata` you may be looking for is hiding under `db.metadata`